# Check key, value of nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm generating a nested dictionary in  my program. After generating, I want to iterate through that dictionary, and check for the dictionary key and value.

**Program-Code**

This is the dictionary I want to iterate whose value contains another dictionary.

```
 main_dict = {101: {1234: [11111,11111],5678: [44444,44444]},
              102: {9100: [55555,55555],1112: [77777,88888]}}
```

I'm reading a csv file and storing contents in this dictionary. Like this :

**Input.csv -**

```
 lineno,item,total
 101,1234,11111
 101,1234,11111
 101,5678,44444
 101,5678,44444
 102,9100,55555
 102,9100,55555
 102,1112,77777
 102,1112,88888
```

This is input csv file. I'm reading this csv file and I want to know for one unique item total is how many times repeating?

For that stuff I'm doing like this :

```
for line in reader:
                if line[0] in main_dict:
                    if line[1] in main_dict[line[0]]:
                        main_dict[line[0]][line[1]].append(line[2])
                    else:
                        main_dict[line[0]].update({line[1]:[line[2]]})
                else:
                    main_dict[line[0]] = {line[1]:[line[2]]}

print main_dict
```

**Output of above program :**

```
 {101: {1234: [11111,11111],5678: [44444,44444]},
  102: {9100: [55555,55555],1112: [77777,88888]}}
```

**but I'm facing following error in this line-**

```
 if line[1] in main_dict[line[0]]:
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Iteration of main_dict-**

```
 for key,value in main_dict.iteritems():
            f1 = open(outputfile + op_directory +'/'+ key+'.csv', 'w')
            writer1 = csv.DictWriter(f1, delimiter=',', fieldnames = fieldname)
            writer1.writeheader()
            if type(value) == type({}):
                for k,v in value.iteritems():
                    if type(v) == type([]):
                        set1 = set(v)
                        for se in set1:
                           writer1.writerow({'item':k,'total':se,'total_count':v.count(se)})
```

I want to know best way to iterate this type of dictionary?

Sometimes I'm getting correct result just like above dictionary but many a times I face this error, what is that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing the check for  `main_dict[line[0]]` to exist - `if not  main_dict[line[0]]: #do whatever you find right to`

Comment: Probably one of the lines is missing information. like it is not complete.

Comment: Can you give us an input csv which fails? I suspect you have an empty line somewhere.

Comment: @dmitryro- After for loop only I'm checking that line[0] is exist or not in main_dict if not then I'm adding whole row.

Comment: @Dean Fenster- Not empty line problem. I added if line: then only operation get perform

Comment: @kit I think @Dean Fenster is right,  `if line` was useless , did you check `if len(line) == 3`?

Comment: @Mithril- yes I'm checking for len(line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments pointed out, you are not checking if `line` is of length 3:

```
for line in reader:
    if not len(line) == 3:
        continue
```

Concerning your algorithm, I would use nested `defaultdict` to avoid the if/else lines.

EDIT: I added a new defaultdict and the csv writing part after the question edit:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

counter = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
main_dict= defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict)))
fieldnames=['item', 'total', 'total_count']

# we suppose reader is a cvs.reader object
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        if not len(line) == 3:
            continue
        # Remove unwanted spaces
        lineno, item, total = [el.strip() for el in line]
        # Do not deal with non digit entries (title for example)
        if not lineno.isdigit():
            continue
        counter[lineno][item].append(total)
        csvdict = {'item': item,
                   'total': total,
                   'total_count': counter[lineno][item].count(total)}
        main_dict[lineno][item][total].update(csvdict)

# The writing part
for lineno in sorted(main_dict):
    itemdict = main_dict[lineno]
    output = 'output_%s.csv' % lineno
    with open(output, 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')
        writer.writeheader()
        for totaldict in itemdict.values():
            for csvdict in totaldict.values():
                writer.writerow(csvdict)
```

You can then use the following function to print a readable representation of the result:

```
def myprint(obj, ntab=0):
    if isinstance(obj, (dict, defaultdict)):
        for k in sorted(obj):
            myprint('%s%s'%(ntab*' ', k), ntab+1)
            myprint(obj[k], ntab+1)
    else:
        print('%s%s'%(ntab*' ', obj))
myprint(main_dict)
```

But if you want to count the item totals, I would use another defaultdict with the total as the key and a tuple (lineno, item) as the value:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

total_dict = defaultdict(list)

# we suppose reader is a cvs.reader object
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        if not len(line) == 3:
            continue
        # Remove unwanted spaces
        lineno, item, total = [el.strip() for el in line]
        # Do not deal with non digit entries (title for example)
        if not lineno.isdigit():
            continue
        total_dict[total].append((lineno, item))
```

You can have the number of each total very easily:

```
>>> print len(total_dict['55555'])
2
```

Comment: @Frodon- I dont want total as a key.I want lineno as a key of dictionary and its value contains another dictionary whose key is item and value is total.

Comment: @kit ok then my first proposal fits your need I guess

Comment: @Frodon- yes but It is giving error in this line **main_dict[lineno][item].append(total)** at first iteration only because first lineno is not present in this main_dict.

Comment: @kit If main_dict is an instance of defaultdict, you should not get an error (this is the point of using defaultdict). Unless the input csv file is not like the one you wrote in your question.

Comment: @Frodon- yeah got it...my mistake bro... but its having the problem in the iteration of this main_dict. I'm editing original question and putting my iteration of main_dict. I want to write different files by reading this main_dict.

Comment: @Frodon- see my edit in the question. you will get clear idea about what I'm trying to do. I want to write different csv files of lineno depend on this item and count. suggest your ans of how to iterate default dict in your ans.

Comment: @Frodon- Actually I want to make program as efficient as so that less time is required for execution. anything  efficient than that because many loops are there. Its also correct no issues..! if anything efficient than this pl edit it.Thanks for help.

Comment: @kit sorry I don't understand what is wrong with my answer. While tested it, it wrote as many csv files as line numbers, with the content fitting your specifications. The `for` loops seem inevitable for me ...

Comment: @kit I updated a bit my answer (without changing the logic)